# Realm: How to use line breaks in database String entry?

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

I am using a Realm DB in my iOS app and wanted to have a long entry broken up by specifically placed line breaks. I inserted  **\n**  into the text but when displayed, these are treated as text rather than newlines.

Is there a way to insert new lines into the String stored in the database that will be recognised when the String is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm stores whatever you put in there, so if you're storing `Swift.String`s, it'll store them exactly byte-for-byte using UTF8 encoding. So really this is a question of how to properly escape newlines in a Swift String.

```
print("a\nb")
// Prints:
// a
// b
```

Same thing goes for Realm:

```
import RealmSwift

class MyModel: Object {
    dynamic var stringProperty = ""
}
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "TemporaryRealm"))
try! realm.write {
    let object = MyModel()
    object.stringProperty = "a\nb"
    realm.add(object)
}
print(realm.objects(MyModel).first!.stringProperty)
// Prints:
// a
// b
```

Comment: You're right, @jpsim, it does work if I do it this way. What I had done, and what doesn't work, is to add the **"\n"** into the text within the RealmBrowser. I was simply testing the layout with some test data and realised I wanted the line breaks, so I went into the Browser to add them. They show up as text rather than line breaks when you do that. I am happy to do it this way instead.

Comment: Great! If my answer to your question is accurate then, I'd appreciate if you could accept it. Thanks!